# What is the OpenCV FindChessboardCorners convention?

Tags: c, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.2.

If I use `cvFindChessboardCorners` to find the corners of a chessboard, in what order are the corners stored in the variable `corners` (e.g. top-left corner first, then row then column)?

[Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findchessboardcorners) (which didn't helped much).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure it orders the chessboard corners by rows, starting with the one closest to the top-left corner of the image.

The chessboard pattern has no specified origin (one of the deficiencies of that calibration device), so if you turn it 90 or 180 degrees the corners you get back won't be in the same order.

The way to make sure is to look at the actual point values you get back and see if they are what you expected.

Edit: at least in case of OpenCV 3.3.1 and 5x3 chessboard, the chessboard corners can be returned either starting top-left or bottom-right, depending on the rotation.

Comment: Can you find any reference supporting that conjecture? Thank's

Comment: I looked briefly through the code in calibinit.cpp, and it appeared that was what was going on. I can't find any specific reference in the documentation though.

Comment: From some tests that I've done it appears you are correct, although I didn't tested all the possibilities (anyone reading this answer should be cautious when implementing something based on this)

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me the doc is lacking this kind of details.

For 3.2.0-dev it seems to me it depends on the angle of rotation of the chessboard.
With this snippet:

```
cv::Size patternsize(4,3); //number of centers
cv::Mat cal = cv::imread(cal_name);
std::vector<cv::Point2f> centers; //this will be filled by the detected centers

bool found = cv::findChessboardCorners( cal, patternsize, centers, cv::CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH );

std::cout << found << "\n";
if(found){      
    cv::drawChessboardCorners(cal,patternsize,centers,found);
```

You will get these results:

First image:
[image]

First image rotated by 180 degrees:
[image]

Note the

> colored corners connected with lines

drawn by `drawChessboardCorners`, they differ only by the color: in the original image the red line is at the bottom, in the rotated image the red line is at the top of the image.
If you pass to `drawChessboardCorners` a grayscale image you will loose this piece of information.

If I need the first corner at the top left of the image and if I can assume that:

1. the angle of the chessboard in the scene will be only close to 0 or close to 180;
2. the tilt of the camera will be negligible;

then the following snippet will reorder the corners if needed:

```
cv::Size patternsize(4,3); //number of centers
cv::Mat cal = cv::imread(cal_name);
std::vector<cv::Point2f> centers; //this will be filled by the detected centers

bool found = cv::findChessboardCorners( cal, patternsize, centers, cv::CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH );

std::cout << found << "\n";
if(found){      
    cv::drawChessboardCorners(cal,patternsize,centers,found);
    // I need the first corner at top-left
    if(centers.front().y > centers.back().y){
        std::cout << "Reverse order\n";
        std::reverse(centers.begin(),centers.end());
    }
    for(size_t r=0;r<patternsize.height;r++){
        for(size_t c=0;c<patternsize.width;c++){
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << "("<<r<<","<<c<<")";
            cv::putText(cal, oss.str(), centers[r*patternsize.width+c], cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 3);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: As long as you use EVENxODD or ODDxEVEN pattern size, the pattern will be asymmetric, meaning its rotation can and will be determined automatically by findChessboardCorners. That's why the red line drawn by drawChessboardCorners starts at different positions in this example. The order of the corners takes into account the rotation of the pattern. In most cases, having this rotation information is explicitly *desired*.